# How to Use Neo4j Load CSV on Azure?

Tags: azure, csv, neo4j

I've followed this tutorial to deploy Neo4j on Azure:
https://neo4j.com/blog/deploy-neo4j-microsoft-azure-part-2/

Does anyone know how to use Load CSV? Or something similar.

I have 2 Mi Nodes that I tested locally, but I'd like to test the performance in the cloud.